# RcppArmadillo: "-=" operation on list elements

Tags: c++, list, rcpp

I have a list of complex matrices with the same `k*k` dimensions, and I need to subtract a `k*k` complex matrix `x` from each element of the list. For my application, `x` would vary depending on the position of the elements in the list, but here for simplicity, `x` is fixed. My code for this task:

```
# include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma; 

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List fn(int& length, int& k) {
  List out(length);
  cx_mat m(k, k, fill::zeros);
  out.fill(m);
  cx_mat x(k, k, fill::ones);
  for(int i=0; i<length; i++) {
    out(i) -= x;
  }
  return out;
}
```

This would throw an error during compiling:

```
g++ -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/library/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/library/RCPPAR~1/include" -I"C:/Users/Shuang/DOCUME~1/MARKOV~1/RCODE~1"  -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c test3.cpp -o test3.o
test3.cpp: In function 'Rcpp::List fn4(int&, int&)':
test3.cpp:77:15: error: no match for 'operator-=' in 'Rcpp::Vector<RTYPE, StoragePolicy>::operator()(const size_t&) [with int RTYPE = 19, StoragePolicy = Rcpp::PreserveStorage, Rcpp::Vector<RTYPE, StoragePolicy>::Proxy = Rcpp::internal::generic_proxy<19>, size_t = long long unsigned int]((* &((size_t)i))) -= x'
make: *** [test3.o] Error 1
```

However, if I change the body of the `for` loop by using an intermediate variable, the code compiles and works fine:

```
# include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma; 

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List fn(int& length, int& k) {
  List out(length);
  cx_mat m(k, k, fill::zeros);
  out.fill(m);
  cx_mat x(k, k, fill::ones);
  for(int i=0; i<length; i++) {
    cx_mat temp = out(i);
    temp -= x;
    out(i) = temp;
  }
  return out;
}
```

I am not very well-versed in C++ to fully grasp what the error message means, but I guess I have some type mismatch here since `List` is an Rcpp type. Is there anyway to make this work without using an intermediate variable? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are jumping back and forth between `arma` and `Rcpp` types, invoking implicit conversions. That sometimes needs help, and your more explicit rewrite provided that help.

Comment: That's what I thought. However, what I don't understand is why `cx_mat temp = out(i)` (initializing an `arma` type matrix using the value of an `Rcpp` type matrix) works. It seems this initialization forces an conversion and that's fine to the compiler, but directly operating on an `Rcpp` type matrix using an `arma` type matrix is not fine (which I can understand). Are you saying there is no easy way to do this without an intermediate variable in this case?